# How can I programmatically access the C Drive on an XPMode Virtual Machine?

Tags: c#, virtual-machine, windows-explorer, xp-mode

Normally, when I build my (Windows CE/.NET prehistoric.archaic) app in Visual Studio 2003 in XP Mode (embedded within -- if that's the correct terminology -- a Windows 7 machine), I copy it from its location on the Virtual Machine's C drive to a "holding tank" on my Windows 7 C drive (which is visible from the XP Mode Explorer) and then I go to the Windows 7 Explorer and copy it from the "holding tank" (it really is, actually, named C:\HoldingTank) to the Handheld device (which I can see from the Windows 7 Explorer, but not from the XP Mode/Virtual Machine Explorer).

Today, though, things have changed. Every time I right-click the .exe and select the "Copy" context menu item, XP Mode/VM "blows up" and immediately tries to reboot itself, with the message:

```
Starting the virtual machine...
```

**NOTE:** This is apparently not specifically related to my .exe file; I get the same result even when I try to copy a text file from the VM via Explorer. Has the XPocalypse arrived?

I also get the message:

[image]

Clicking the link to see the detail:

[image]

When I click the "View technical information" link, I see:

[image]

So, since it claims more info is available in that .dmp and .xml file, I try to navigate to that location, but my XPMode VM has no "Locals~1" folder beneath \Documents and Settings\clay:

[image]

This wouldn't be a location in Explorer on my Windows 7 machine, would it? That folder is locked; when I try to open it, I get, "*Documents and Settings is not accessible Access is denied*"

So...as there are reportedly multiple ways to de-skin a feline, I'm wondering if (question title) I can programmatically access the C Drive on the XPMode Virtual Machine, so that I can copy over the .exe that way.

Does anybody know how that can be done?

### UPDATE

The folder specified has three files in it:

```
manifest.txt
Mini073014-03.dmp
sysdata.xml
```

**Manifest.txt** contains:

```
Server=watson.microsoft.com
UI LCID=1033
Flags=1696080
Brand=WINDOWS
TitleName=Microsoft Windows
DigPidRegPath=HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DigitalProductId
ErrorText=A log of this error has been created.
HeaderText=The system has recovered from a serious error.
Stage2URL=
Stage2URL=/dw/bluetwo.asp?
BCCode=1000007e&BCP1=C0000005&BCP2=00000000&BCP3=B59611A8&BCP4=B5960EA4&OSVer=5_1_2600&S
P=3_0&Product=256_1
DataFiles=C:\DOCUME~1\clay\LOCALS~1\Temp\WER57b8.dir00\Mini073014-03.dmp|C:\DOCUME~1\clay
\LOCALS~1\Temp\WER57b8.dir00\sysdata.xml
ErrorSubPath=blue
DirectoryDelete=C:\DOCUME~1\clay\LOCALS~1\Temp\WER57b8.dir00
```

**Mini073014-03.dmp** => When I tried to open this, XPMode instantiates Visual Studio 2010 Shell, which then tells me, "*Debugging older format crashdumps is not supported*"
("then why did it ***CREATE*** an older format crash dump" I silently, plaintively, reply)

**sysdata.xml** contains a TON of information (and, AFAICT, nothing enlightening re: this crash; it does not contain the words "error" or "exception"), in fact, too much to include here; I'll just show the first part and the last part:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Unicode" ?>
<SYSTEMINFO>
<SYSTEM>
    <OSNAME>Microsoft Windows XP Professional</OSNAME>
    <OSVER>5.1.2600 3.0</OSVER>
    <OSLANGUAGE>1033</OSLANGUAGE>
</SYSTEM>
<DEVICES>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>ACPI Fixed Feature Button</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>ACPI\FixedButton</HARDWAREID>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Programmable interrupt controller</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>ACPI\PNP0000</HARDWAREID>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>System timer</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>ACPI\PNP0100</HARDWAREID>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Direct memory access controller</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>ACPI\PNP0200</HARDWAREID>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Standard 101/102-Key or Microsoft Natural PS/2 Keyboard</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>ACPI\PNP0303</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>i8042prt</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>i8042prt.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Printer Port</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>ACPI\PNP0400</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>Parport</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>parport.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Communications Port</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>ACPI\PNP0501</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>Serial</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>serial.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Communications Port</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>ACPI\PNP0501</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>Serial</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>serial.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Standard floppy disk controller</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>ACPI\PNP0700</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>fdc</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>fdc.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>System speaker</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>ACPI\PNP0800</HARDWAREID>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>PCI bus</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>ACPI\PNP0A03</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>pci</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>pci.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>System CMOS/real time clock</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>ACPI\PNP0B00</HARDWAREID>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>System board</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>ACPI\PNP0C01</HARDWAREID>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Motherboard resources</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>ACPI\PNP0C02</HARDWAREID>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Motherboard resources</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>ACPI\PNP0C02</HARDWAREID>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Numeric data processor</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>ACPI\PNP0C04</HARDWAREID>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Microsoft PS/2 Mouse</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>ACPI\PNP0F03</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>i8042prt</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>i8042prt.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Virtual PC Guest Bus Driver</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>ACPI\VPCBus</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>vpcbus</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>vpcgbus.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Microsoft ACPI-Compliant System</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>ACPI_HAL\PNP0C08</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>ACPI</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>ACPI.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Floppy disk drive</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>FDC\GENERIC_FLOPPY_DRIVE</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>flpydisk</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>flpydisk.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>CD-ROM Drive</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>IDE\CdRomMS_C/DVD-ROM____________________________3.0_____</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>cdrom</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>cdrom.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Disk drive</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>IDE\DiskVirtual_HD______________________________1._1____</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>disk</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>disk.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>ISAPNP Read Data Port</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>ISAPNP\ReadDataPort</HARDWAREID>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Sound Blaster 16 or AWE32 or compatible (WDM)</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>ISAPNP\TBA03b0</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>ctlsb16</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>ctlsb16.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Printer Port Logical Interface</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>LPTENUM\MicrosoftRawPort958A</HARDWAREID>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Intel 21140-Based PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter (Generic)</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>PCI\VEN_1011&amp;DEV_0009&amp;SUBSYS_21140A00&amp;REV_20</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>DC21x4</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>dc21x4.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Virtual PC Integration Components S3 Trio32/64</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>PCI\VEN_5333&amp;DEV_8811&amp;SUBSYS_00000000&amp;REV_00</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>vpc-s3</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>vpc-s3.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Intel 82371AB/EB PCI to ISA bridge (ISA mode)</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>PCI\VEN_8086&amp;DEV_7110&amp;SUBSYS_00000000&amp;REV_01</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>isapnp</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>isapnp.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Intel(R) 82371AB/EB PCI Bus Master IDE Controller</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>PCI\VEN_8086&amp;DEV_7111&amp;SUBSYS_00000000&amp;REV_01</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>intelide</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>intelide.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Intel 82443BX Pentium(R) II Processor to PCI Bridge</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>PCI\VEN_8086&amp;DEV_7192&amp;SUBSYS_00000000&amp;REV_03</HARDWAREID>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Primary IDE Channel</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>Intel-PIIX4</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>atapi</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>atapi.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Secondary IDE Channel</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>Intel-PIIX4</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>atapi</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>atapi.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Advanced Configuration and Power Interface (ACPI) PC</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>acpipic_up</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>\Driver\ACPI_HAL</SERVICE>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Logical Disk Manager</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>ROOT\DMIO</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>dmio</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>dmio.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Volume Manager</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>ROOT\FTDISK</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>ftdisk</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>ftdisk.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Audio Codecs</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>MS_MMACM</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>audstub</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>audstub.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Legacy Audio Drivers</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>MS_MMDRV</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>audstub</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>audstub.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Media Control Devices</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>MS_MMMCI</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>audstub</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>audstub.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Legacy Video Capture Devices</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>MS_MMVCD</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>audstub</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>audstub.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Video Codecs</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>MS_MMVID</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>audstub</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>audstub.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>WAN Miniport (L2TP)</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>ms_l2tpminiport</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>Rasl2tp</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>rasl2tp.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>WAN Miniport (IP)</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>ms_ndiswanip</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>NdisWan</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>ndiswan.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>WAN Miniport (PPPOE)</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>ms_pppoeminiport</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>RasPppoe</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>raspppoe.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>WAN Miniport (PPTP)</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>ms_pptpminiport</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>PptpMiniport</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>raspptp.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Packet Scheduler Miniport</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>ms_pschedmp</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>PSched</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>psched.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Packet Scheduler Miniport</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>ms_pschedmp</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>PSched</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>psched.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Direct Parallel</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>ms_ptiminiport</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>Raspti</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>raspti.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Terminal Server Device Redirector</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>ROOT\RDPDR</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>rdpdr</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>rdpdr.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Terminal Server Keyboard Driver</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>ROOT\RDP_KBD</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>TermDD</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>termdd.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Terminal Server Mouse Driver</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>ROOT\RDP_MOU</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>TermDD</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>termdd.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Plug and Play Software Device Enumerator</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>root\swenum</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>swenum</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>swenum.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Microcode Update Device</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>root\update</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>update</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>update.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Microsoft System Management BIOS Driver</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>root\mssmbios</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>mssmbios</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>mssmbios.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Virtual PC Application Services</DESCRIPTION>
        <HARDWAREID>VPCsystem</HARDWAREID>
        <SERVICE>VPCAppSv</SERVICE>
        <DRIVER>VPCAppSv.sys</DRIVER>
    </DEVICE>
    . . .
</DEVICES>
<DRIVERS>
    <DRIVER>
        <FILENAME>acpi.sys</FILENAME>
        <FILESIZE>187776</FILESIZE>
        <CREATIONDATE>04-14-2008 06:30:00</CREATIONDATE>
        <VERSION>5.1.2600.5512</VERSION>
        <MANUFACTURER>Microsoft Corporation</MANUFACTURER>
    <PRODUCTNAME>
Microsoft® Windows® Operating System</PRODUCTNAME>
    </DRIVER>
    <DRIVER>
        <FILENAME>acpiec.sys</FILENAME>
        <FILESIZE>11648</FILESIZE>
        <CREATIONDATE>04-14-2008 06:30:00</CREATIONDATE>
        <VERSION>5.1.2600.0</VERSION>
        <MANUFACTURER>Microsoft Corporation</MANUFACTURER>
    <PRODUCTNAME>
Microsoft® Windows® Operating System</PRODUCTNAME>
    </DRIVER>
    <DRIVER>
        <FILENAME>adv01nt5.dll</FILENAME>
        <FILESIZE>4255</FILESIZE>
        <CREATIONDATE>07-02-2013 19:15:52</CREATIONDATE>
        <VERSION>6.13.1.3198</VERSION>
        <MANUFACTURER>Intel(R) Corporation</MANUFACTURER>
    . . .
    <DRIVER>
        <FILENAME>watv06nt.sys</FILENAME>
        <FILESIZE>22271</FILESIZE>
        <CREATIONDATE>07-02-2013 19:15:46</CREATIONDATE>
        <VERSION>6.13.1.3198</VERSION>
        <MANUFACTURER>Intel(R) Corporation</MANUFACTURER>
    <PRODUCTNAME>
Intel(R) Graphics Accelerator Drivers for Windows NT(R)</PRODUCTNAME>
    </DRIVER>
    <DRIVER>
        <FILENAME>watv10nt.sys</FILENAME>
        <FILESIZE>25471</FILESIZE>
        <CREATIONDATE>07-02-2013 19:15:46</CREATIONDATE>
        <VERSION>6.13.1.3198</VERSION>
        <MANUFACTURER>Intel(R) Corporation</MANUFACTURER>
    <PRODUCTNAME>
Intel(R) Graphics Accelerator Drivers for Windows NT(R)</PRODUCTNAME>
    </DRIVER>
    <DRIVER>
        <FILENAME>wdf01000.sys</FILENAME>
        <FILESIZE>492000</FILESIZE>
        <CREATIONDATE>11-02-2006 04:22:54</CREATIONDATE>
        <VERSION>1.5.6000.0</VERSION>
        <MANUFACTURER>Microsoft Corporation</MANUFACTURER>
    <PRODUCTNAME>
Microsoft® Windows® Operating System</PRODUCTNAME>
    </DRIVER>
    <DRIVER>
        <FILENAME>wdfldr.sys</FILENAME>
        <FILESIZE>32224</FILESIZE>
        <CREATIONDATE>11-02-2006 04:22:52</CREATIONDATE>
        <VERSION>1.5.6000.0</VERSION>
        <MANUFACTURER>Microsoft Corporation</MANUFACTURER>
    <PRODUCTNAME>
Microsoft® Windows® Operating System</PRODUCTNAME>
    </DRIVER>
    <DRIVER>
        <FILENAME>wdmaud.sys</FILENAME>
        <FILESIZE>83072</FILESIZE>
        <CREATIONDATE>06-27-2009 13:49:00</CREATIONDATE>
        <VERSION>5.1.2600.5512</VERSION>
        <MANUFACTURER>Microsoft Corporation</MANUFACTURER>
    <PRODUCTNAME>
Microsoft® Windows® Operating System</PRODUCTNAME>
    </DRIVER>
    <DRIVER>
        <FILENAME>wmilib.sys</FILENAME>
        <FILESIZE>4352</FILESIZE>
        <CREATIONDATE>04-14-2008 06:30:00</CREATIONDATE>
        <VERSION>5.1.2600.0</VERSION>
        <MANUFACTURER>Microsoft Corporation</MANUFACTURER>
    <PRODUCTNAME>
Microsoft® Windows® Operating System</PRODUCTNAME>
    </DRIVER>
    <DRIVER>
        <FILENAME>ws2ifsl.sys</FILENAME>
        <FILESIZE>12032</FILESIZE>
        <CREATIONDATE>04-14-2008 06:30:00</CREATIONDATE>
        <VERSION>5.1.2600.0</VERSION>
        <MANUFACTURER>Microsoft Corporation</MANUFACTURER>
    <PRODUCTNAME>
Microsoft® Windows® Operating System</PRODUCTNAME>
    </DRIVER>
</DRIVERS>
</SYSTEMINFO>
```

At least this proves that information overload isn't just for Congress anymore.

### UPDATE 2

I ended up going back to a restore point of Monday, when I was last able to copy a file without the VM crashing, and it is back to abnormal (which is better than the VM-from-Dallas state it was in).

Comment: `Locals~1` is actually referring to the hidden `Local Settings` folder.  You need to change Explorer's "Show hidden files and folders" to on to see it.

Comment: Yes, that gives me access to those files, thanks; I'll post anything "interesting" there in an update.